# In order By how to set character at first and symbol at last

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Below is my code

```
List<User> listOfUsers = new List<User>()
{
   new User() { Key = "AFG", Value = "Afghanistan" },
   new User() { Key = "ALA", Value = "Åland Islands"},
   new User() { Key = "BHR", Value = "Bahrain" },
   new User() { Key = "ARG", Value = "Argentina"},
};

List<User> usersByAge = listOfUsers.OrderBy(user => user.Value).ToList();
foreach (User user in usersByAge)
{
    var k = user.Key;
    var v = user.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(user.Key + ": " + user.Value);
 }


class User
{
public string Key { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**I want Åland Islands to be display at last in the list instead of second as Åland Islands has symbol instead of A**

As per my code it is displaying at 2nd but I want to Åland Islands to display at last

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: If you use `StringComparer.CurrentCulture` as the second parameter on your call to `OrderBy()` and have the relevant culture set on the current request/thread, then it'll sort according to that culture's ordering rules. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.currentculture?view=net-6.0

Comment: A dictionary is never sorted. If you apply first OrderBy and then ToDictionary, you are destroying the order.

Comment: @MartinCostello can you help me more giving short example?

Comment: @KiranJain There is sample code in the link I shared.

Comment: @SomeBody can you help me how to make the code working well with needed requirements

Comment: In which culture do you need the accented letters to come at the end of the list though? In British English for example, that doesn't happen. You could use Swedish for example, but that might be odd for your application. So you could do this `.OrderBy(l => l, StringComparer.Create(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE"), false))` for example.

Comment: @DavidGreplace by orderby as .OrderBy(l => l.Value, StringComparer.Create(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE"), false)) but it is not working

Comment: @MartinCostello I have troed replacing my orderby as .OrderBy(kv => kv.Value, StringComparer.CurrentCulture) but it s not working

Comment: I have updated my question with example , can any one try on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `StringComparer.Ordinal`, that sorts according to the unicode codepoint.

Just replace with this:

```
List<User> usersByAge = listOfUsers.OrderBy(user => user.Value, StringComparer.Ordinal).ToList();
```

Now Åland will be last.